# Fitting runtime buttons inside a form

Tags: vb.net

I have a number of buttons between 5-20 and it's variable each time the form loads based on the user settings. I am trying to fit all these buttons on my form no matter what the size of the form is. The buttons are generated during runtime. I would like the first button to be 20 points from the top bar (at any size) and the rest of the buttons simply to fit in the form. This is what I have now but I have to maximize the form to view them all and also while I'm expanding the form the space between the buttons decreases and they overlap with each other whereas they should keep a relative distance. Any ideas?

```
    Dim iButtonWidth, iButtonHeight, iVerticalSpace As Integer

    If UserButtons.Count > 0 Then
        iButtonHeight = Me.Size.Height - (Me.Size.Height * 0.85)
        iButtonWidth = Me.Size.Width - (Me.Size.Width * 0.5)
        iVerticalSpace = iButtonHeight / 3
        For Each btn In UserButtons
            btn.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(iButtonWidth, iButtonHeight)
            btn.Location = New Point(20, 20 + btn.TabIndex * iVerticalSpace * 3)
        Next
    End If
```

Comment: Check out a FlowLayoutPanel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171633(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Jason Faulkner Yes. I do use the anchorStyles. However, those depend after my first load which is what the above link does by hardcoding the buttons' location. I'm using location coordinates based on the form's dimensions.

Comment: Add and Dock.Fill your Buttons in a [TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with your desired number of rows/columns.  Make sure to setup the TableLayoutPanel itself to resize with the Form using Anchor and/or Dock properties as well.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I think this is the best solution. However only the first two rows appear and then I have to resize the form to view them all. If I restore the form to it's initial size then the buttons appear (but the first two much bigger than the rest). Please put this as answer and I will mark it as accepted solution. Also, any input on my current problem will be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example using the TableLayoutPanel to play with:

[image: TableLayoutPanel with 5 Columns and a Variable number of Rows]

```
Public Class Form1

    Private UserButtons As New List(Of Button)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Static R As New Random

        Dim NumButtons As Integer = R.Next(5, 21) ' "a number of buttons between 5-20 and it's variable each time"
        UserButtons.Clear()
        For i As Integer = 1 To NumButtons
            Dim btn As New Button()
            btn.Text = i.ToString("00")
            btn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill ' Optional: See how you like it with this on vs. off
            UserButtons.Add(btn)
        Next

        DisplayButtons()
    End Sub

    Private Sub DisplayButtons()
        TableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Clear()

        TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Clear()
        TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 5 ' Fixed Number of Columns
        For i As Integer = 1 To TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount
            TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 911)) ' the size doesn't matter here, as long as they are all the same
        Next

        ' Variable Number of Rows:
        Dim RowsRequired As Integer = ((UserButtons.Count - 1) \ TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount) + 1 ' Integer Division
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear()
        TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = RowsRequired
        For i As Integer = 1 To TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 911)) ' the size doesn't matter here, as long as they are all the same
        Next

        TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.AddRange(UserButtons.ToArray)
        TableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The TableLayoutPanel itself had all four sides turned on in its Anchor() Property.

Comment: great answer and very interesting profile on EE. I enjoyed reading every line.

Comment: At the moment we are adding one button for on every cell of the table. What if I want to add two labels on the same cell i.e. one for the title and one for the description? How would the 'AddRange' or some other method handle that?

Comment: You can add a Control to a specific cell of the TableLayoutPanel like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he3sxc2a(v=vs.110).aspx).  You can also add other containers to a cell, so you could embed a Panel, or even another TableLayoutPanel at each position so you can put more than one control there.  Another option is to simply use multiple rows/columns for each "set" of controls.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what kind of container are the buttons in?  You should be able to set the container's AutoScroll property to true - then when controls within it spill out of the visible bounds you will get a scroll bar.

Then also what you could do is draw each button in more of a table with a certain number next to each other before dropping down to the next line (instead of just 1 button on each line).  If that is an option that works for you then you could get more buttons within the visible space.

I happen to have an example to do the same thing with picture boxes (and text boxes under each picture box).  Hope this helps:

```
    Dim point As New Point(0, 0)
    'create 11 picture and text boxes-you can make this number the number your user selects.
    Dim box(11) As PictureBox
    Dim text(11) As TextBox
    Dim i As UInt16

    For i = 0 To 11  'or whatever your number is
        box(i) = New PictureBox
        box(i).Width = 250     'your button width
        box(i).Height = 170    'your button height
        box(i).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle

        box(i).Location = point
        layoutsPanel.Controls.Add(box(i))  'my container is a panel

        text(i) = New TextBox
        text(i).Height = 50
        text(i).Width = 250

        point.Y += box(i).Height
        text(i).Location = (point)
        layoutsPanel.Controls.Add(text(i))

        point.Y -= box(i).Height    'reset Y for next picture box

        'Put 4 picture boxes in a row, then move down to next row
        If i Mod 4 = 3 Then
            point.X = 0
            point.Y += box(i).Height + text(i).Height + 4
        Else
            point.X += box(i).Width + 4
        End If
    Next
```